# Cannot access global variable declared inside $.get() from outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

So, here's the code

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $.get("json_family.php", {}, function(data) {
        families = data;
    }, 'json');

    console.log(families);

// Some other codes here
});
```

And here's what happens when I try to run it:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: families is not defined
```

So, what gives? I thought variables declared without the `var` keyword would be global no matter where it is declared.

Comment: This needs some more explanation about when declared/undeclared variables are created.

Comment: Undeclared variables will be global, but they are [not created before code execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var). Your code `families=data` will be executed only after the requested resource is loaded via ajax. So at the time you are logging the variable `families` does not exist and throws error.

Comment: I read the possible duplicate. So, to summarize, this won't work unless: a) I call `console.log()` from inside the `get` or b) I wrap `console.log()` inside another function, and call _that_ function from inside the `get`. Is that correct?